# Excel column names

Tags: excel, ado.net

What column names cannot be used when creating an Excel spreadsheet with ADO.

I have a statement that creates a page in a spreadsheet:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableName] (Column string, Column2 string);
```

I have found that using a column name of `Date` or `Container` will generate an error when the statement is executed.

Does anyone have a complete (or partial) list of words that cannot be used as column names?  This is for use in a user-driven environment and it would be better to "fix" the columns than to crash.

My work-around for these is to replace any occurences of `Date` or `Container` with `Date_` and `Container_` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use brackets for any fieldname, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableName] ([Date] string, [Container] string)
```

Full example:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\test.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"))
{
  conn.Open();
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [TableName] ([Date] string, [Container] string)", conn);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This was the best answer to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here are the reserved words for MS Query:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125948

Cell naming rules:

http://ezinearticles.com/?Rules-For-Naming-Cells-in-Microsoft-Excel&id=218607

Comment: I still cannot find why "container" is flagged as invalid.  Definitely like the cell naming rules link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems more like an issue with SQL reserved words. This is a [good list](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/sql-reserved-words.tml)